# Save scroll state in Windows Phone 8.1 when user navigate between pages

Tags: scrollviewer, windows-phone-8.1

I navigate between pages with Navigation Helper class which VS 2013 added when solution created, But scroll state most of controls (Like Pivot, Hub) does not saved like in Windows Phone 8.x Silverlight.

What should I do for implement this behaviour? Should I handle scrolling state by myself and restore scroll when i go back in visited page?

Thanks.

**UPDATE1:**

I need save selected pivot/hub item etc, when i go back to page.

**UPDATE2:**

```cs
    void navigationHelper_SaveState(obj sender,SaveStateEventArgs e)
    {
    e.PageState["SelectedSection"] = MainHub.SectionsInView;
    }
    void navigationHelper_LoadState(obj sender,LoadStateEventArgs e)        
    {
        if (e.PageState != null)
        {
            var sections = e.PageState["SelectedSection"] as IList<HubSection>;
            if (sections != null && sections.Any())
                MainHub.ScrollToSection(sections[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by scroll? The selected pivot or hub item, or the scrollviewer position of items inside pivot or hub?

Comment: Selected pivot / hub item.

Comment: If you create a new Pivot type of Windows Phone 8.1 project and run it as is, you'll see that it keeps the state of selected pivot item when you navigate from the pivot page to the item page and back.

Comment: Ok, I have Hub in Mam page. I need to do something like this? (please, see Update2)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the page where you use the hub, set the navigation cache mode in constructor:

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
```

or in XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App.HubPage"
    ....
    xmlns:data="using:App.Data"
    NavigationCacheMode="Enabled"
    ....
```

Comment: I don't know why this isn't default behaviour (especially on hub pages). Glad I found this before saving/loading state via NavigationHelper like I had planned.

Comment: try suspension and this way is useless

Answer (score 1):

Better use:

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
```

before:

```
this.InitializeComponent();
```

And add:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
    this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;
}
```

to remove cache on back navigation from page.

Comment: That is actually a pretty clever trick. Imo a lot better than the top question. Thanks a lot!